# How to find tabular data in Excel sheet

Tags: java, apache-poi, xls, jxl

I have a excel file named abc.xls in my c: drive (local computer) , now in that excel file in the first sheet itself there is a table as shown below,

```
TradeRef   TMS  Deal     Date        B/S
12         45   DRT    23/97/2014    RTY  
23         36   QWE    21/07/2015    WER
```

Now please advise how to read this table from the excel sheet through apachae poi in java.

Now the problem is that this table can be at any range with in the sheet, for example, it may be starting with A1 cell or it may be starting with F25, so in other words the table can be at any range in the sheet. My concern is to reach to the starting point of that range where the TradeRef is there first, please advise how to get there and then print the contents into the console?

Answer (score 2):

Mi first advice is agreeing on the starting cell with the program (or the human) who writes to the Excel file - or at least require that a human opens the sheet and then invokes your program with the right parameters like

```
# F25 is the starting cell, 120 the number of rows
java trade.App F25 120
```

Otherwise you are left with the heuristic approach of [iterating](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator) over the cells of the sheet and assuming the starting point as the first cell whose text content is "TradeRef" (or more sophisticated variants like checking for all the headers you expect)

```
public Cell findFirstRow(Sheet sheet) {
  for (Row row : sheet) {
    for (Cell cell : row) {
      if (cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING
          && "TradeRef".equals(cell.getStringCellValue()
      ) {
        int row = cell.getRowIndex() + 1;
        int col = cell.getColumnIndex();
        if (sheet.getRow(row) == null)
          throw new RuntimeException("Row " + row + 1 + " is empty!");
        Cell startOfFirstDataRow = sheet.getRow(row).getCell(col);
        if (startOfFirstDataRow == null) {
          CellReference ref = new CellReference(row, col);
          throw new RuntimeException("Data not found at " + ref.formatAtString());
        }
        return startOfFirstDataRow;
      }
    }
  }
  throw new RuntimeException("TradingRef header cell not found!");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Can you please advise how can i call this from main method in java , request you to please edit the code and show please how can we call this from main method in java itself

Comment: This is all the code you need to solve your problem. Learning to code in Java is up to you and can't be done here on StackOverflow

Comment: getting an exception that can not get a text value from a numeric cell

Comment: Then you have to adjust the code to check if the cell contains text data before reading the cell content as a String

Comment: Thanks a lot for quick advise , really appreciated but please advise where i have to make necessary changes in your above mentioned code please

Comment: Before calling cell.getStringCellValue

Comment: can you please how to implement this check please i have tried but still i am getting the error

Comment: i have added cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING); inside for loop itself

Comment: Wrong. You should just check the type before getting the content as text, not changing it!

Comment: Raffaele I am not able to grasp please can you show in the post itself so that i can grasp please

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work for you:

```
  try {

        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\test.xls"));

        //Get the workbook instance for XLS file 
        HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(file);

        //Get first sheet from the workbook
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        //Iterate through each rows from first sheet
        Iterator<row> rowIterator = sheet.iterator();
        while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            //For each row, iterate through each columns
            Iterator<cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
            while(cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

                    if (cell == null || cell.getCellType() == Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK) {

                        switch(cell.getCellType()) {
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                                System.out.print(cell.getBooleanCellValue() + "\t\t");
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue() + "\t\t");
                                break;
                            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue() + "\t\t");
                                break;
                        }
                    }
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
       file.close();
    }
```